# Calculate date for particular day in Teradata

Tags: date, datetime, time, teradata

How to calculate date for current week Friday in Teradata? I need a general function that can calculate date for friday for any week.
thanks

Comment: What's your TD release? And how do you define a week, starting on monday or sunday?

Comment: Teradata version 13.10.0214 I am considering week as from Friday to Friday. For this case I want Avg. Amount for Last 6 months. So whenever report is run on any day of week it should consider current day as Friday no matter report is run on which day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TD14 there's Oracle's `NextDay`, to get the next friday:

```
NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE-1, 'FRI')
```

Before you can calculate it based on a function named `day_of_week` (or `td_day_of_week`):

```
(CURRENT_DATE + 7) - td_day_of_week(CURRENT_DATE + 1)
```